# Handling complex post-login redirection logic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, authentication, logic

I have a rails app that needs to redirect users to different pages based on some criteria after they log in (using Devise & OmniAuth). This logic could be pseudo-coded like this:

```
if the user is an admin
    if no url was specified before login (original_uri)
        - redirect to admin panel
    else
        - redirect to original_uri
else
    if the user filled up his profile data
        if no url was specified before login
            - redirect to user's home page
        else
            if original_uri is allowed (not restricted to that user)
                - redirect to original_uri
            else 
                - redirect to user's home page
    else
        - redirect to profile page
```

or as an rspec integration example:

```
describe "complex routing" do

  context "user is an admin" do

    let(:user) { create(:admin) }

    context "an original URL was specified before login" do
      it "redirects to the original URL"
    end

    context "no original URL was specified" do
      it "redirects to the admin panel"
    end

  end

  context "user is not an admin" do

    let(:user) { create(:user, :completed_profile => false) }

    context "with complete profile info" do

      before(:each) { user.completed_profile = true }

      context "an original URL was specified before login" do
        it "redirects to original URL if not restricted"
        it "redirects to home page if URL is restricted"
      end

      context "no original URL was specified" do
        it "redirects to home page"    
      end

    end

    context "with incomplete profile" do
      it "redirects to profile page"
    end

  end

end
```

As can be seen, this gets quite complex and not very obvious (or easy to test). In addition, the thought of this sitting in a `before_filter :decide_routing` as a method call makes me cringe.

What would be a good way to abstract this and make this cleaner, testable and simpler to manage in the future (in case more logic needs to be added or changed)?

Any thoughts will be great - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this does it?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # if user is not active, redirect him so he completes registration
    if resource.active?
      super
    else
      # complete_the_effing_registration_path
    end
  end
end
```